# Stack too deep, try removing local variables. _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);

Tags: solidity, remix, bitcoin

I need help, i don't understand this Error...

Code:

```
function _transferFromExcluded(address sender, address recipient, uint256 tAmount, bool lottery, bool updateWinner) private {
    uint256 currentRate =  _getRate();
    
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee, uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tBurn) = _getValues(tAmount);
    uint256 rBurn =  tBurn.mul(currentRate);
    
    _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
    _rOwned[sender] = _rOwned[sender].sub(rAmount);
    _rOwned[recipient] = _rOwned[recipient].add(rTransferAmount);   
    _reflectFee(rFee, rBurn, tFee, tBurn);
    if (lottery == true && updateWinner == true) {
        uint winnings = getTotalWon(recipient);
        uint256 _totalWin = winnings.add(tTransferAmount);
        updateWinnings(recipient, tTransferAmount, _totalWin);
    } 
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tTransferAmount);
}
```

Erro:

```
CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables. _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount); ^----^
```